# How to create a center div scrolling with the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website and I would like to put a DIV above this website with field to enter e-mail and button "Subscribe". It should work like this advertisements that we all like. So this div should be always on the center of the screen, and it should be "above" the website and scroll while user is browsing though  the page. When user clicks X it should close.

How to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the CSS [`position:fixed`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#positioning-scheme) and [`z-index`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index) properties. To center the item horizontally and vertically, give it fixed dimensions, position it at 50%,50%, and then use negative margins. For example:

```
#annoying-floater {
  z-index:10;
  position:fixed;
  top:50%; left:50%;
  width:640px; height:480px;
  margin-left:-320px; margin-top:-240px
}
```

To 'close' it, set the `display` to `none` via JS. For example:

```
window.onload=function(){
  document.getElementById('annoying-floater-closer').onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById('annoying-floater').style.display='none';
  }
}
```

Comment: What to do to make it work in IE8? Rectangle is far left up on the browser window.

Comment: @tomaszs It works correctly for me in IE8, both in and out of compatibility view. Here's [a simple test case](http://phrogz.net/tmp/annoyer.html) showing it in action.

Answer (score 2):

do you mean that as the page scrolls the div will stay centered? in that case, use position: fixed to place your div; which will work except for < IE8, to get that to work there, use [this](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/fixedPosition.html)

Comment: oh, yeah, and z-index as well.